# Dialogflow how to instantiate a sessionPath with both location and environment

Tags: dialogflow-es

I got a dialogflow agent located in `europe-west1`. Actually I'm trying to use the dialogflow's builtin environment system but I got a problem:

```
const contextsClient = new dialogflow.v2beta1.ContextsClient({ apiEndpoint: `${REGION_ID}-dialogflow.googleapis.com` })
const sessionClient = new dialogflow.v2beta1.SessionsClient({ apiEndpoint: `${REGION_ID}-dialogflow.googleapis.com` })

const sessionPath = sessionClient.projectLocationAgentSessionPath(PROJECT_ID, REGION_ID, sessionId)
await contextsClient.createContext({
  parent: sessionPath,
  context: {
    name: `projects/${PROJECT_ID}/locations/${REGION_ID}/agent/environments/${ENVIRONMENT}/users/-/sessions/${sessionId}/contexts/${namespace}`,
    lifespanCount: 1
  }
})
```

For now google returns me the following error:

```
INVALID_ARGUMENT: com.google.apps.framework.request.BadRequestException: Context 'projects/project-name/locations/europe-west1/agent/environments/dev/users/-/sessions/3e3bc716-b164-4fe0-aa51-aeb42cf4930a/contexts/search' does not belong to session 'projects/project-name/locations/europe-west1/agent/sessions/3e3bc716-b164-4fe0-aa51-aeb42cf4930a'
```

Is there any `sessionClient.projectLocationEnvironmentAgentSessionPath` method? Can't find it in API's doc.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found it, only available on 4.X dialogflow.v2beta1 release. The method is `.projectLocationAgentEnvironmentUserSessionPath(PROJECT_ID, REGION_ID, ENVIRONMENT, '-', sessionId)`

Answer (score 0):

Just as additional information to `@Pierre Clocher` answer.

[Dialogflow Essential](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs) is not fully supporting `projectLocationAgentSessionPath` yet, however you can find it is supported by [Dialogflow CX](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs).

In `Dialogflow CX` documentation - [Interactions with the API](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/quick/api?hl=ru#detect-intent) you can find that `sessionPath` has what you need.

```
  const sessionPath = client.projectLocationAgentSessionPath(
    projectId,
    location,
    agentId,
    sessionId
  );
```

However in `Dialogflow ES`, in [Quickstart: Interactions with the API](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/quick/api#detect-intent-text-nodejs) is mention that you can use

```
  const sessionPath = sessionClient.projectAgentSessionPath(
    projectId,
    sessionId
  );
```

There is already a `Feature Request` reported to Google via `Issue Tracker`, that `Dialogflow ES` could support `ProjectLocationAgentEnvironmentSessionPath`. This `Issue Tracker` can be found here: [Support ProjectLocationAgentEnvironmentSessionPath](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/181036938).

Reporter of this `Feature Request` also provided a workaround so it might work for you as well.

```
    const projectLocationAgentEnvironmentPath = sessionClient.projectLocationAgentEnvironmentPath(
      projectId,
      location,
      environment
    );
    const sessionPath = `${projectLocationAgentEnvironmentPath}/users/-/sessions/${sessionId}`;
```

### Summary:

1. Use `@Pierre Clocher` solution
2. You could use `Dialogflow CX` instead of `Dialogflow ES`.
3. Try to use a workaround from `Issue Tracker` and click on `+1` button in the `Issue Tracker` which will indicate that this `FR` is needed.